# my jquery toggle function is not toggling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get the button to toggle between showing text in different languages. When I click the button nothing happens, can someone help out please?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[lang="jp"]').hide();
  $(document).on('click', '#switch-language', function() {
    $('[lang="en"]').toggle();
    $('[lang="jp"]').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="switch-lang">Switch Language</button>
<p lang="en">eigo</p>
<p lang="jp">en japon</p>
```

Comment: Everything is correct except id name, id name must be same

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your Selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[lang="jp"]').hide();
  $(document).on('click', '#switch-lang', function() {
    $('p[lang="en"]').toggle();
    $('p[lang="jp"]').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="switch-lang">Switch Language</button>
<p lang="en">eigo</p>
<p lang="jp">en japon</p>
```

No element has "switch-language" as the ID. When you change it to the correct value, "switch-lang", it works.